# How to right align text

Tags: android, android-layout

I was trying to change the alignment of text. This is what i have:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TableLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TableRow>
         <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ctime"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:text="time" />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow>

           <TextView
               android:id="@+id/cstatus"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_gravity="right"
               android:layout_weight="100"
               android:text="status" />

</TableRow>
</TableLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
```

Everything is left-aligned in the output even after setting `android:layout_gravity="right"`.
This is a part of the layout, as I cant post the entire layout.

Comment: [Similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5711046/right-aligning-text-in-android)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this one

```
android:gravity="right"
```

Comment: Yes, @arnab321, just remember, any of the XML attributes preceded by `layout_` affect the View itself, while the others work on the content of the View.

Comment: Oh thanks! I thought Layout_gravity and gravity were the same. So i posted this question and ignored the similar questions